# How does shift work in a scope definition?

Tags: tikz-styles

I've added a snippet of code; I'd like to shift the filled semi-circle from (0,0) to (0,1), but I have to shift it (-5.5,-4.5). It gives me what I want, but I'd rather know what I did wrong and how to fix it rather than use a workaround.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,cap=round,>=latex,baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\begin{axis}[
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  width=1.0\linewidth,
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=both,
  %axis equal,
  axis equal image,
  grid style={very thin,cyan!50},
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5,
  %ytick=\empty,
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  %xtick=\empty,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  %xticklabels={},
  yticklabels={$\ds -5i$,$\ds -4i$,$\ds -3i$,$\ds -2i$,$\ds -i$,$\ds 0$, $\ds i$,$\ds 2i$,$\ds 3i$,$\ds 4i$,$\ds 5i$},
  xlabel=$\cal R$,
  ylabel=$\cal I$,
  %xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}:00},
  %xticklabel style={rotate=0,anchor=north east}
  ]

    \draw [blue,thick,dashed] (0,1) circle[radius=1];   
    \addplot [->,blue, domain=-3.7:2.5, samples=500,thick,<->] {x*sqrt(3)+1};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-5.5,-4.5)}]
    \fill[blue!40,opacity=0.25] (60:0) coordinate (beta) arc (60:-120:0) coordinate (alpha) -- (-120:1) arc (-120:60:1) -- cycle; 
    \end{scope}
    \draw [black] (0,0) circle[radius= 0.3 em];     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Try using `shift={(axis cs:0,1)}` or `shift={(axis direction cs:0,1)}`.

Comment: If you wish to have a complete answer, please make your code compilable by promoting it to a minimal working example. And `\cal` was retired in the previous millennium, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the coordinate `(0,1)` does not have the components (in the sense of pgf components) you expect it to have. You need to subtract the pgf coordinates of the origin. The following does that with `calc`. This is not the only way, and not the shortest (the shortest is probably `shift={(axis direction cs:0,1)}` [suggested by Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537018/how-does-shift-work-in-a-scope-definition#comment1356772_537018)), but it is perhaps the most didactic way because from the syntax you see that we shift by the difference between the coordinates `(0,1)` and `(0,0)` (where `(0,0)` has nontrivial pgf components). You also had an arc of radius 0, which I removed, and for a linear plot you do not need 500 samples. I also do not know how `\ds` is defined but for the issue here this is not relevant, so I removed the ticks using the unknown macro. Please note that I use version `1.16` even though `1.17` is out because many TeXLive users do not have `1.17` installed. However, this also works with `1.17`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,cap=round,>=latex,baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\begin{axis}[
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  width=1.0\linewidth,
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=both,
  %axis equal,
  axis equal image,
  grid style={very thin,cyan!50},
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5,
  %ytick=\empty,
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  %xtick=\empty,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  %xticklabels={},
  %yticklabels={$\ds -5i$,$\ds -4i$,$\ds -3i$,$\ds -2i$,$\ds -i$,$\ds 0$, $\ds i$,$\ds 2i$,$\ds 3i$,$\ds 4i$,$\ds 5i$},
  xlabel=$\mathcal{R}$,
  ylabel=$\mathcal{I}$,
  %xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}:00},
  %xticklabel style={rotate=0,anchor=north east}
  ]

    \draw [blue,thick,dashed] (0,1) circle[radius=1];   
    \addplot [->,blue, domain=-3.7:2.5, samples=2,thick,<->] {x*sqrt(3)+1};
    \begin{scope}[shift={($(0,1)-(0,0)$)}]
    \fill[blue!40,opacity=0.25] (60:0) coordinate (beta)  
        -- (-120:1) coordinate (alpha)
        arc[start angle=-120,end angle=60,radius=1] -- cycle; 
    \end{scope}
    \draw [black] (0,0) circle[radius= 0.3 em];     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Cat, it worked beautifully. \ds is \displaystyle, and 500 was a left over, a bit over the top, I agree.